# Defining default function parameters in C++ Builder class and Too few parameters error

Tags: c++, c++builder, c++builder-2010

I have a class that defines a function with default parameters. It works fine as long as function definition is in header file before function that calls it.

However if I move it after the calling function C++ Builder (2010) reports Too few parameters error.

header might be for example:

```
class TSomething
{
public:
void CallingFunction();
void Function(int a);
}
```

and cpp file might be:

```
#include "Header.h"

TSomething::CallingFunction()
{
Function(); // "Too few arguments" here...
}

TSomething::Function(int a = 123)
{
//... some code here ...
}
```

So if calling function is before "Function" it reports Too few parameters. I do not understand why because it includes function definition in #include statement in cpp file. Can anyone tell me how to rearrange this so it accepts properly default arguments? I can move the Function(int a) above the CallingFunction to make it work so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put the default arguments in member function's declaration inside your class:

```
void Function(int a = 123);
```

Also, remove the default arguments from the definition outside of your class.

Comment: Thanks... works now. And the minute I typed it in I also understood why it works and my version didn't... dumb...dumb...dumb! In declaration and definition the parameter was always after the calling function.